# QT Visual Studio Tools Embedded compile and debug

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cross-compiling

Is it possible to use "Qt Visual Studio Tools" with a Raspberry Pi or other embedded Device to compile and debug applications.

Maybe in combination with VS Linux Support?

I know with QT it's possible but you need the arm compiler on the host system.
VS Linux Support as far as i understand compiles on the slave system.